# Uncomment code (CTRL + K + U) only works when the session is disconnected in SQL Server Management Studio v18.4

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone have the solution to the following issue happening in the **SSMS v18.4**?

We are unable to uncomment code in the SQL Server session by pressing the designated shortcut (**CTRL + K + U**) while the session is connected to SQL Server instance. It only works when the session is disconnected (mostly when we open the SSMS and let sessions in disconnected mode).

Please find the version, OS details as below:

[image]

When the session is in disconnected mode, pressing **CTRL + K + U** works fine:

[image]

otherwise, pressing **CTRL + K + U** acts like pressing **CTRL+U** (select database shortcut) only:

[image]

It's very strange and I couldn't find a solution yet.

I have also checked in the SSMS options and it says the same but doesn't work
[image]

Comment: `CTRL+U` of selected test should make it UPPER case

Comment: that is CTRL+SHIFT+U (to make uppercase), CTRL+U gives you option to select the database by default.

Comment: @Sasce, no it is not - check the docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-keyboard-shortcuts?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @gotqn, the link mentions `Ctrl+U` for lower case only in reference to some "SQL Server 2019 (15.x)" which isn't exactly clear (especially considering that versions of SQL Server and SSMS don't follow each other anymore). The hotkey does work in this way in SSDT projects, however.

Comment: @RogerWolf You can read this as `2008R2` and `later` - the docs is update on `03/14/2017`. I am using the SSMS 18.4 and SQL Server 2016SP1 and the shortcuts works as they are described.

Comment: @gotqn you are absolutely right but we have asked the question only because we are experiencing some problem and are thinking that someone else might have already faced this issue and has some solution for it.

Comment: could you try renaming the extension of the .vssettings file in %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\18.0_IsoShell\Settings\SQL Server Management Studio and let ssms recreate the settings file after restarting it?

Comment: @Iptr I backed up the existing setting file and removed the file. After restarting SSMS, it prompts some warning messages which I ignored but nothing changes and it also didn't create a new .vssettings file at the location. When I closed SSMS again, it created the new .vssettgins file but nothing changed.

Comment: @Iptr though I was very hopeful that after creating the fresh settings file everything will be perfect.

Comment: @Iptr and Thanks! for the suggestion.

Comment: could you check if you have the Edit.UncommentSelection in the <UserShortcuts> section of the vssettings file? (the file is also created when quitting ssms). For eg. i have changed mine to uncomment using ctrl+K+P: `           <Shortcut Command="Edit.MakeUppercase" Scope="XMLA Query Editor">Ctrl+Shift+U</Shortcut>
          <Shortcut Command="Edit.UncommentSelection" Scope="Global">Ctrl+K, Ctrl+P</Shortcut>
          <Shortcut Command="Edit.WordTranspose" Scope="Text Editor">Ctrl+Shift+T</Shortcut>`

Comment: @lptr Yes, it's there with value <Shortcut Command="Edit.UncommentSelection" Scope="Global">Ctrl+K, Ctrl+U</Shortcut> and same exist in the backup file.

Comment: there is also another file ApplicationPrivateSettings.xml in folder 18.0_IsoShell, which most likely holds the global settings... i have changed  that to ctrl+K+O for uncommenting: `{"Key":"{5EFC7975-14BC-11CF-9B2B-00AA00573819}.Ctrl+K, Ctrl+O.A", `   ... as a result, i can now uncomment using ctrl+K+O (from global), ctrl+K+P from the newsettings  ...and ctrl+K+U ???!!!

Comment: @lptr Thanks so much!!! I changed both .settings and ApplicationPrivateSettings.xml with CTRL+K, CTRL+O and it works. I changed both back to default again but it didn't work. Anyway, I can use the new combination to uncomment. Thanks!. Please put that in the answer and I can accept that answer.

Comment: have you tried removing [Remove button] all shortcuts/entries for UncommentSelection and first create a global (PressKeys:ctrl+K+U) check if it works and then create the same for TextEditor? Having a different shortcut is a bit cumbersome (isnt it?). In my case, ctrl+k+u worked because the shortcut was assigned to the TextEditor (although it didnt appear (?) at first in the shortcuts editor, but it did so after restarting my pc). Manually changing the files (ApplicationPrivateSettings.xml & NewSettings.vssettings) created two global shortcuts for the same action.

Comment: @lptr I tried that already but it didn't help, only adding a new combination works.

Answer (score 0):

The [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-keyboard-shortcuts?view=sql-server-ver15) is:

```
CTRL + K + C
```

to comment and

```
CTRL + K + U
```

to remove comment.

Comment: I have modified the question if that's misleading. I am using the same CTRL + K + U to remove the comment.

Comment: @sacse when you are uncommenting, is the commented text selected?

Comment: it doesn't work, either way, selected text or just the cursor on the line which I want to uncomment.